# how to add dependent library(jar) to scala project in Eclipse/Scala IDE

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, scala-2.10

I am trying to create a spark scala project, and i have added dependency for spark core in build.sbt file. But, the dependent jars are not visible in Scala IDE(eclipse) for the project. So could not call any relevant class in my scala object.

Does sbteclipse plugin help my cause, if so, how could i add plugin to sbt.? I am working in windows environment, and where could i add plugin in sbt.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does sbteclipse plugin help my cause

Yes. Just follow the instructions in the README.

> I am working in windows environment, and where could i add plugin in sbt.?

`project/whateverName.sbt`, just as in any OS, or `%HOME%/.sbt/0.13/whateverName.sbt` (`HOME` should normally be `C:\Users\YourUserName` under Windows) if you want to add it for all projects.